# How do I only show items that belong to a certain user (using restful_authentication)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web application with users and their documents. Each user can have many documents:

user.rb:

```
has_many :documents
```

document.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
```

document_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @documents = Document.find(:all)
end
```

I am using the restful_authentication plugin. Here is my question: How do I get the controller to only show documents that belongs to each user? Right now it shows all the documents for all the users.

I am using the latest version of Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M000530) in the rails API in the Association Join Models section.

However be aware Restful authentication won't control access in order to limit the users to only their own records particularly with restful routes.  They can still view other users' records by entering values in the urls once they are logged in.

For that you might want to look into [Restful ACL](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/966-restful-acl)

Answer (score 7):

You set a relationship in your User class to your Document class. This will automatically add a method to your User objects that returns a list of all documents related to a particular user:

```
def index
  @documents = @current_user.documents
end
```

See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001111) for other automatically added methods.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
def index
    @documents = Document.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def index
  @documents = Document.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => session[:user_id]})
end
```